# Math error in python causing TypeError

Tags: python

After I enter the price of paint per gallon the program crashes. Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code? I'm using python.

```
 def main():

    # Ask for the square footage of wall space to be painted.
    square_footage = input('Enter the number of square feet to be painted: ')

    # Ask for the price of the paint per gallon.
    price_gallon = input('Enter the price of the paint per gallon: ')

    estimate(square_footage, price_gallon)

def estimate(square_footage, price_gallon):
    # 115 sq ft = 1 gallon + 8 hrs of labor (labor is $20 per hour)
    num_gallons = square_footage/115
    hours_labor = num_gallons * 8
    total_price_gallon = num_gallons * price_gallon
    total_labor = hours_labor * 20
    final_total = total_price_gallon + total_labor
    print 'The total estimated price for this paint job is $', final_total

# Call the main function.
main()
```

And the Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "D:\Users\harve_000\Desktop\Painting.py", line 21, in <module> main() 
    File "D:\Users\harve_000\Desktop\Painting.py", line 9, in main estimate(square_footage, price_gallon) 
    File "D:\Users\harve_000\Desktop\Painting.py", line 13, in estimate num_gallons = square_footage/115 
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: You need to cast the `input` to `int`, you trying to perform arithmetic using strings, also you should post the full traceback rather than telling us it crashes, it's useful to know **where** it crashes

Comment: @EdChum: The need for casting depends on the version that OP uses. We can't be sure of that

Comment: Correct, this script runs in Python 2.7.9. However, you also need to replace 115 by 115.0 to ensure the maths works correctly.

Comment: @AswinMurugesh version of python you mean? I'm assuming not python 3 given the `print` statement

Comment: @EdChum: So Python 2.7 does not need casting if OP uses `input()` statement

Comment: The fact remains we need more info and the traceback

Comment: A full Stack Trace can help knowing the cause here

Comment: int for input does nothing to solve the issue. The input is for the user to enter their information.

Comment: Yes that does not make a difference. We will be able to help only if you post the entire Stack Trace of the error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\harve_000\Desktop\Painting.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Users\harve_000\Desktop\Painting.py", line 9, in main
    estimate(square_footage, price_gallon)
  File "D:\Users\harve_000\Desktop\Painting.py", line 13, in estimate
    num_gallons = square_footage/115
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Post the traceback in your question, not as a comment, the error is pretty damn clear to me

Comment: After you change `input()` to `int(input())`, do you get a different error? w.r.t to the print statement?

Comment: If its clear why not answer it and help me? I'm looking for help here.

Comment: >>> 
Enter the number of square feet to be painted: 20
Enter the price of the paint per gallon: 20
The total estimated price for this paint job is $, final_total
>>>  So now there are no errors but I am not receiving an actual price for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

It crashes becauseby default `input()` returns a string and not an integer/float and therefor you need to change it.

```
def main():

    # Ask for the square footage of wall space to be painted.
    square_footage = float(input('Enter the number of square feet to be painted: '))

    # Ask for the price of the paint per gallon.
    price_gallon = float(input('Enter the price of the paint per gallon: '))

    estimate(square_footage, price_gallon)
```